# Android value reading from custom keyboard keys. giving java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am using my custom keyboad in which i have 0 to 9 and " . " means decimal . cause entering the floating value ,but when i am trying to read the value from edittext app is crashing.

from sample app i have taken this

```
<Key
            android:codes="8226"
            android:keyLabel="."
            android:keyWidth="20%p" />
```

but i think this is not correct code for period or decimal (see between 12 and 45)(i.e 12.45).

```
 String str ="12.56"
    double num = Double.parseDouble(str);
```

This giving correct result.

but this code is cause of crashing .

```
String str =edittext.getText().toString();
    double num = Double.parseDouble(str);
```

any one can help .

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long

`"12.56"` is not `long` , you cannot parse it to `long`. Secondly , this exception will be thrown if you use `Long.parseLong()`. Something is not in sync between the posted code and exception message. Also [trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) the `String` to get rid of extra spaces.

Comment: my mistake its double ...sorry

Comment: the problem in keycode i think ,i got only this 8226 for decimal (.)

Answer (score 0):

change this `String str =edittext.getText().toString();` with `String str =edittext.getText().toString().trim();`

it should work. Basically you need to trim the string.